# Future-proof command

Tags: macros

In my preamble I have:

`\newcommand{\myvecb}[1]{\vb{#1}}`

Suppose in some math context I use:

`\myvecb{F}_y`

while in some other I have:

`\myvecb{F_T}`

**My problem**

I have noticed that in the future I may want to change all `\myvecb{F}_y` to `\myvecb{F_y}` (or, in some other context, perhaps vice versa). Instead of doing everything manually (because a simple regex replace may too complicated for some reason), is it possible to define `\myvecb` command definition such that I can manipulate the stated-problem within the definition?

Comment: Yes. `\makeatletter \newcommand*\myvecb[1]{\@ifnextchar_{\myvecbaux{#1}}{\vb{#1}}} \def\myvecbaux#1_#2{\vb{#1_#2}} \makeatother`.

Comment: @Manuel Thank you. Is your solution just for one character? (For instance I may have `\myvecb{F}_{A|B}`.

Comment: Ah, add braces around `#2` in `\vb{#1_{#2}}`.

Comment: Super easy with xparse, I think the new e type was made for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This checks if a `_` is following and in that case it grabs the following `_{..}` and puts it as a subscript inside `\vb{..}`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\myvecb[1]{\@ifnextchar_{\myvecbaux{#1}}{\vb{#1}‌​}}
\def\myvecbaux#1_#2{\vb{#1_{#2}}}
\makeatother
```